# How to change browser tab displayed text in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I'm trying to implement a notification functionality which would change the browser tab text with the number of notifications. I searched on the internet and found that I should change the title which would change the browser tab text too . But it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I tried:

```
var nbNotifications = 0;

$().ready(function() {
    var docOriginalTitle = "Tab does not change on notification";
    debugger;
    document.title = docOriginalTitle;
    $('#test').click(function() {
        nbNotifications += 1;
        document.title = "(" + nbNotifications + ") " + docOriginalTitle;
        alert(document.title);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/BishopBarber/setqdf8d/2/)

Perhaps, it's not true that the document title changes the browser tab title? Or maybe it doesn't work with JSFiddle?

Could you put me on the good track?

**Edit**

I'm trying to change the browser tab text *in JSFiddle*. Is there a way to cheat JSFiddle and render this behaviour?

Comment: problem is jsfiddle parent document is not on the same domain as the *results* iframe. afaik this will not be possible unless jsfiddle offers the capabilities via their api. in other news, trying to close your fiddle bugged my chrome. http://i.imgur.com/lIqyPo9.gif

Answer (score 1):

I think this technique works just fine. I think the problem is that jsFiddle runs your page in an iframe, which does not control the browser tab title.

If I enter `document.title = 'Here's my new Title';` in the browser console, the text in the browser tab *does* update.

How else have you tested this?

Comment: Actually, my goal is to change the browser tab text in JSFiddle. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The problem is that you don't write that page, the folks at jsFiddle do. You have to inject your JavaScript in the main page somehow. And I suspect security measures would prevent that, except for just editing it temporarily in the console of your browser.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for the clear explanations! I guess I'll just add a sound notification instead.

Answer (score 1):

`document.title` is the way to go, but it won't work in jsFiddle.  It should work fine in a "real" page.

Try typing `javascript:alert(document.title = "My new title");` into your browser - you should see the tab text update.

**Edit**:

I don't think you can do this in jsfiddle unless they allow for it somehow.  If you try to "escape" your window and change properties on theirs (i.e. `parent.document.title = "xxx";` you get a security exception:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://jsfiddle.net". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the most important part in my question. My goal is to change the browser tab text in JSFiddle, because my app is actually a JSFiddle app.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.